# MySqlException .NET Core 2.1: Unknown column 'xxxx' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Estou com um erro bizarro que gostaria de compartilhar com vocês.

Estou usando o Visual Studio 2017 e criando uma aplicação MVC com NET Core 2.1, baseado em um banco de dados MySQL e tabelas que já existiam anteriormente.

Eu criei uma model chamada Resultado e criei as Annotations para fazer o link corretamente com a tabela e o banco de dados. Porém, depois de criada a classe, eu resolvi mudar o nome das colunas na tabela. Obviamente, também alterei as Annotations para refletir corretamente as alterações.

Porém, quando vou fazer alguma consulta a esta tabela, a aplicação devolve erro dizendo que a coluna xxxxxx (e aí mostra o nome antigo da coluna) não existe na tabela, mas eu mudei o nome dela no banco e mudei na classe, porém, a recompilação não está refletindo esta mudança.

Para deixar mais claro, vou deixar o código da classe logo abaixo:

---

```
[Table("ProvasResultados")]
public class Resultado
{

    public Resultado() { }

    [Key]
    [Column("Ano")]
    public int Ano { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column("Prova")]
    public int ProvaId { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column("Atleta")]
    public int AtletaId { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column("Grupo")]
    public int GrupoId { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column("Atividade")]
    public int AtividadeId { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column("Tentativa")]
    public byte Tentativa { get; set; }

    [Column("Tempo")]
    public Nullable<System.TimeSpan> TempoRegistrado { get; set; }

    [Column("Indice")]
    public Nullable<decimal> IndiceRegistrado { get; set; }

    [Column("Pontuacao")]
    public Nullable<bool> Pontuacao { get; set; }

    [Column("MelhorDoDia")]
    public Nullable<bool> MelhorDoDia { get; set; }

    [Column("MelhorDoAno")]
    public Nullable<bool> MelhorDoAno { get; set; }

    [Column("RecordePessoal")]
    public Nullable<bool> RecordePessoal { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Ano, GrupoId, AtividadeId")]
    public AtividadePorGrupo GrupoAtividade { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Ano, ProvaId")]
    public Prova Prova { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Ano, ProvaId, AtletaId")]
    public Inscricao Inscricao { get; set; }
}
```

---

Porém, quando o MVC vai "montar o select" para recuperar os dados da tabela, observei no painel de erros que o select está como abaixo

---

```
SELECT p.Ano, p.Prova, p.Atleta, p.Grupo, p.Atividade, p.Tentativa, p.IndiceAno, p.IndiceId, p.Indice, p.MelhorDoAno, p.MelhorDoDia, p.Pontuacao, p.RecordePessoal, p.Tempo
FROM ProvasResultados AS p
WHERE (p.Ano = @__Ano_0) AND (p.Prova = @__Prova_1)
```

---

E o erro:

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Unknown column
>   'p.IndiceAno' in 'field list

Onde a coluna "MelhorDoAno" é agora a antiga "IndiceAno". Ou seja, o MVC não está refletindo as alterações na classe que eu estou determinando.

---

Lembrando que é a primeira vez que mexo com .NET Core 2.1, por isso estou apanhando um pouco, gostaria de saber se alguém pode me ajudar com este problema.

Desde já agradeço a ajuda de todos

Comment: Editei a descrição para detalhar melhor o erro. Inseri os códigos e o erro que está acontecendo.

Comment: Atualização. Olhando para a classe e para o SELECT que está sendo montado para o MVC, acabei de identificar que as colunas p.IndiceAno e p.IndiceId são "fantasmas" (rs), ou seja, não eram para estar ali, não foram configuradas, não existem na tabela. Como é que eles foram parar ali? Acho que aí fica mais claro ainda a ajuda que estou precisando.